# Why is it not possible to cast a char to a double

Tags: c

at work a low level trainee asked me why c99 does not allow us to cast a char to a double,
since a cast from char to int works and a cast from int to double obv.

I know that chars are stored in integers (ascii), but if that is so, why cant we cast it directly into a double.

Comment: who said it was not possible? Did you try? It just isn't generally advised

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not sure I understand what you are asking. You can do `char ch = 1; double d = (double) ch;`

Comment: @Filelengthgetter Change your "ow level trainee".:)

Comment: @GarrGodfrey *It just isn't generally advised* - Well depends on the reason to do so. Its perfectly legit for, for example, calculating the average of a bunch of `char`s

Comment: I wonder if the trainee tried to cast a `char*` or `char[]` to `double`? (This is why we ask for code in questions; see [mre].)

Comment: I just did `double d = 'a'; printf("%f\n", d);` and it printed 97.000000, as expected.  No warnings, no errors.  (No explicit casts, either.  Tested under two different compilers.)

Comment: @Filelengthgetter: I know this question has been closed, but some of us who commented or answered are curious what the root of the problem was. What exactly was the trainee trying to do? (BTW, the rules are the same in all versions of C, not just C99.)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Even to average chars, probably more efficient to sum up into an `int` and then convert to double.  If you processor supports double arithmetic, storing signed numbers in 8bits is usually unnecessary. Plus, beginners get confused converting '1' to a double and not getting 1.0

Answer (score 2):

When I tried it worked just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch = 'g';
    double d = (double)ch;

    printf("%lf\n", d);
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc -Wall test.c -o test` with no warnings. Ran it and got:

```
103.000000
```

Now, if you need to do this, you probably want to document clearly why you're doing this in your code, and evaluate whether there are better solutions to the problem you're trying to solve.

As noted by @Keith Thompson in the comments, and thank you to him for pointing it out, the explicit cast in `double d = (double)ch;` is not necessary in the above code. However, you may find it a useful bit of documentation. Maximizing clarity in any code you write is critical.

Comment: And in fact the cast isn't necessary. Since `char` and `double` are arithmetic types, they can be implicitly converted to each other by an assignment, initializer, function argument or `return` statement.